# I use Laravel and I have this problem how can i solve it this is the Erorr

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

PS

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master> php artisan serve
```

> require(C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master/vendor/autoload.php): Failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master\artisan on line 18
>
> Warning:
> require(C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master/vendor/autoload.php): Failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master\artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal error:
> Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master/vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master\artisan:18 Stack trace:
> #0 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master\artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master/vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master\artisan:18 Stack trace:
> #0 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master\artisan on line 18 PS C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom-oniza-master>

PHP Warning:

Comment: have you installed composer?

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags - or explain how this problem is related to MySQL

Answer (score -2):

The required file "autoload.php" is missing in the "vendor" directory of your project. maybe try this to install the required dependancies:

'''
composer install
'''

After running the above command, try running the server again using the following command:

'''
php artisan serve
'''

hopefully it helps!

Comment: I try but not work